# How do I enable JBoss' Sax Error Handler for a deployed app?

Tags: error-handling, jboss, jboss7.x

I am deploying an application (GeoServer) to JBoss EAP 7.4. It deploys, and runs fine but I'm seeing a lot of these errors logged by the application:

```
2023-05-23 16:42:43,980 ERROR [stderr] - Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
2023-05-23 16:42:43,995 ERROR [stderr] - set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
2023-05-23 16:42:44,006 ERROR [stderr] - ErrorHandler to print the first 10 errors.  Please call
2023-05-23 16:42:44,010 ERROR [stderr] - the 'setErrorHandler' method to fix this.
2023-05-23 16:42:44,025 ERROR [stderr] - Error: URI=null Line=1: Document root element "coverageStores", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
2023-05-23 16:42:44,037 ERROR [stderr] - Error: URI=null Line=1: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
2023-05-23 16:42:44,055 ERROR [stderr] - Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
2023-05-23 16:42:44,075 ERROR [stderr] - set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
```

How do I tell JBoss that the application should be allowed to use the ErrorHandler?

I told jboss that xerces was a dependency for the application but that didn't work. Is there another setting to add?

Here is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure
    xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <sub-deployment name="geoserver.war">
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jsf" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api" />
            <module name="javax.xml.transform" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
            <module name="javax.activation.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
            <module name="org.reactivestreams" />
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```